# Use kafka-avro-console-producer without autoregister the schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to use kafka-avro-console-producer 5.4.0-ccs without to autoregister the schema. I tried with:

`--producer-property auto.register.schemas=false`

and

`--property auto.register.schemas=false`

But it's registering the schema anyway. The property seems correct: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/a0a04628687a72ac6d01869d881a60fbde4177e7/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.java#L54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the property is `auto.register` for the CLI instead of `auto.register.schemas`. I found it in the code but it may change in next versions since and it isn't documented.