# Use kafka-avro-console-consumer with already registered schema - error 500

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Using the kafka-avro-console-producer cli
When trying the following command

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
 --broker-list <broker-list> \
 --topic <topic>  \
 --property schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081 \
 --property value.schema.id=419
```

I have this error

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema {...} 
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Internal Server Error; error code: 500
```

I can’t understand why is it trying to register the schema as the schema already exists and I’m trying to use it through its ID within the registry.

Note: my schema registry is in READ_ONLY mode, but as I said it should not be an issue right?

Comment: FYI, there's been a list of issues reported with the 500 error, with no real solution. Auto registering just disables the HTTP call, but doesn't really fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I needed to ask the producer not to try to auto register the schema using this property

```
--property auto.register.schemas=false
```

Found out here [Use kafka-avro-console-producer without autoregister the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067142/use-kafka-avro-console-producer-without-autoregister-the-schema)